# How to find the null space of $T (x, y, z) = (x + y + z, y + z, 3x + y, 2y + z)$?

Tags: vector-spaces

> Find the null space of $T (x, y, z) = (x + y + z, y + z, 3x + y, 2y + z)$.

Question I'm doing ask. Find the the matrix $M_T$ of $T$ find the null space of $T$. Find a basis for the range of $T$.

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&1\\ 0&1&1 \\ 3&1&0 \\ 0&2&1 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$R_3-3R_1, R_3+2R_3;R_4-2R_2$$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&1\\ 0&1&1 \\ 0&0&-1 \\ 0&0&-1 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0\\ 0&1&0 \\ 0&0&1 \\ 0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Do I let $z = t$?

Oh wait did I just prove that $\operatorname{null}{T} = \ker{T} = {0}$?

Or does the $3$ pivots mean my null space is $3$?

Comment: how we have 3 pivots?

Comment: According to me,  nullapace is{0} because x=y=z=0..is the only solution but we can check it other way around by substituting usual basis and get the images and write that in linear combination using the usual basis of R ^4..get the matrix representation and bring that to echelon form, the number of non zero rows forms the rank and the number of free variables is the null space.

Comment: Wait so rank is 3 right?

Comment: Yes....use the thm dim(V)= nullity +rank.

Comment: so i could say dim(ker(T)) + dim(im(T) = rank, 0+dim(im(T)) = 3, since dim(ker(T)) = 0, invertible and injective. Dim(im(T)) = 3 = dim(codomain).  So surjective?

Comment: If it is finite dimensional, then u r right...invertible implies onto implies oneone

Comment: Assuming your basis (you don't write these) in $\mathbb{R^3}$ and $\mathbb{R^4}$, since your computations in rows are right (then the nature of space of solutions is the same of genuine $T$ represented by $M_T$), the scalar equations for null space yet have written in a comment by an user, and the vectorial equation is $M_T\cdot V=0$, where you want find what $V=(x,y,x)\in\mathbb{R^3}$ wich are $T(V)=0\in\mathbb{R^4}$, then your computations from vectorial equation give us the scalar equations $x=0,y=0,z=0$ (and the true statement $0=0$). Thus $ker(T)=\{0\}$, where this last $0\in\mathbb{R^3}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the nullspace i.e v \in V such that T(v)=0.hence equate x+y+z=0,y+z=0,3x+y=0,2y+=0. Bring to echelon form, solve for x,y,z, you will get the basis for null space..

Answer (score 1):

Your reduction to the echelon form is correct.

To know the null space of $T$, we essentially need to describe all the vectors inside it. Hence, we need to solve $T(x,y,z) = (0,0,0,0)$. Doing this in terms of matrices, we solve $$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 3 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$ Now you reduced this correctly to echelon form correctly, meaning we are left with the system of equations $$
\pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0} \pmatrix{x \\ y \\ z} = \pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\0 \\ 0}
$$ Translating the back into equations, we just get $x=y=z=0$. The fourth row of this matrix does not say anything except $0 = 0$.

The null space of $T$ is just the point $\{(0,0,0)\}$ (which means $T$ is injective). So indeed, $\operatorname{Null}(T) = 0$